# Implementation of resource bundle in spring

Tags: spring, resourcebundle

I am implementing Resource bundle in spring for the project, project is pretty huge and has complex folder structure ,I am confused of the folder strure I would like to know which file should go where .Basically I am using a property file and a xml file to configuring the property file then displaying the key in jsp.

Answer (score 1):

Spring's abstraction of resource bundle is called [MessageSource (3.8.2. Internationalization using MessageSources)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html). Google for it and you would find lot of tutorials on it (Best one is Spring's own reference doc). You can follow [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-resource-bundle-with-resourcebundlemessagesource-example/) to use Java's resource bundle.

And follow [this blog](http://mhimu.wordpress.com/2007/12/10/spring-mvc-tutorial-2/) to use it a web app